# Ractive.js Nested list from a single array of items with parent relationship

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, ractivejs

You have a list of items with `id`, `parentid`, and `message` properties. `parentid` references other item in the same list. There is no limit on nested levels. How would you implement this?

In other words, how to take this:

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        parentid: 0,
        message: "I'm 1, and I have no parent."
    }, {
        id: 2,
        parentid: 1,
        message: "I'm 2, and 1 is my parent."
    }, {
        id: 3,
        parentid: 1,
        message: "I'm 3, and 1 is my parent."
    }, {
        id: 4,
        parentid: 0,
        message: "I'm 4, and I have no parent."
    }, {
        id: 5,
        parentid: 1,
        message: "I'm 5, and 2 is my parent."
    }
];
```

And turn it into this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        I'm 1, and I have no parent.
        <ul>
            <li>
                I'm 2, and 1 is my parent.
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        I'm 5, and 2 is my parent.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                I'm 3, and 1 is my parent.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        I'm 4, and I have no parent.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a nice and fast way how to do this in a template? Without looping through the whole array, building a new one, and rendering that?

And even than, what is the best implementation of a template that is recursively rendering itself until there is nothing left?

Comment: Assuming on last data item `id: 5`, should be `parentid: 2`, not `parentid: 1`

Comment: Wanted to fix that, but "Edits must be at least 6 characters" :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ractive.js, you could use javascript to filter the array using a partial and an expression helper function (see http://jsfiddle.net/pUf5P/1/ for full example)

Template:

```
{{# { index: 0 } }}
{{>lister}}
{{/ }}

<!-- {{>lister}} -->
  <ul>
  {{# filter(list, .index) }}
    <li>{{message}}
      {{# { index: id } }}
         {{>lister}}
      {{/ }}
   </li>
  {{/ }}
  </ul>
<!-- {{/lister}} -->
```

Setup:

```
new Ractive({
    el: 'body',
    template: '#template',
    data: { 
        list: data,
        filter: function(list, parent){
            return list.filter(function(item){
                return item.parentid === parent
            })
        }      
    }
})
```

Or for a pure template solution (see http://jsfiddle.net/pUf5P/2/), you can do:

```
{{# { index: 0 } }}
{{>lister}}
{{/ }}

<!-- {{>lister}} -->
  <ul>
    {{#list}}
    {{# .parentid === index}}
    <li>{{message}} 
      {{# { index: .id } }}  
        {{>lister}}
      {{/ }}   
    </li>
    {{ /}}
  {{/list }}
  </ul>
<!-- {{/lister}} -->
```

UPDATE: I know you wanted to do this "Without looping through the whole array, building a new one", but realize that you are looping through the whole array at each level to find the matching children.  You don't need to build a hierarchical structure, just bucket the items based on parent id (see http://jsfiddle.net/pUf5P/3/):

```
var byParent = {}
data.forEach(function(item){
    if(!byParent[item.parentid]){ byParent[item.parentid] = [] }
    byParent[item.parentid].push(item)
})
```

Then use a variant of the above template strategy:

```
{{# { index: 0 } }}
{{>lister}}
{{/ }}

<!-- {{>lister}} -->
  <ul> 
    {{# { list: byParent[index]} }}
      {{#list}}
      <li> {{(.message)}}
        {{# { index: .id } }}
        {{>lister}}
        {{/ }}            
      </li>
      {{/list}}
    {{/ }}

  </ul>
<!-- {{/lister}} -->
```

Comment: Yeah. Doing one loop to generate the bucket is way faster than pure template or filtering solution. Dunno what else was I expecting :/ Thx for the answer :)